# How to create a CGColorSpaceRef that is of format RGBAh?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image

What is the analog to CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB that creates a RGBAh color space? I need to feed this CGColorSpaceRef to a CIContext object (via context:withOptions:).

For clarity, here's what I'm looking for code-wise:

```
[CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:self.eaglContext
   options:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : /* something here of format RGBAh */}];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See supported pixel formats [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB). You just need to pass the proper flags for 16bpp when creating the graphics context.

Comment: So it looks like you can't have an alpha channel when using 16bpp?

Comment: And how do you create a CGColorSpaceRef (from those constants) that can be included in the CIContext options?

Answer (score 0):

CGColorSpaceRef do not have a pixel format (e.g.RGBAh) but you can ask a colors space for its CGColorSpaceGetModel (e.g. kCGColorSpaceModelRGB)

CGImageRefs do have a pixel format but do not support RGBAh.

CIImage* in contrast does support RGBAh.